# Line Break is not being inserted

Tags: html, pdf

I am using activePDF and trying to insert line break but it seems to be ignored by activePDF api, or maybe it's something related to PDF ?

```
<p>aaa&p</p>
<p>aaa</p> "<br />"
<p>aaa</p>
<div>aaa "/n" aaaa</div>
<div>aaaaaaa</div>
<p>aaa</p>
<p>aaa</p>
<p>aaa</p>

<div style=\"border: 1pt solid red; font: bold 12pt Arial;background: threedface; color: white; padding-Top: 5px; padding-Bottom: 6px; background-Image: url(http://www.meadroid.com/images/act_bg.jpg)\"><center> --- Header for page <b> &p </b>--- </center></div>
```

gives me this text,

> aaa&paaa""aaaaaa"/n"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa---Headerforpage&p---

[Documentation - Page 98](http://www.activepdf.com/AltDownloads/Examples/Toolkit/VBS/Linearization/Linearized.pdf)

Comment: Does the method support HTML? I don't find anything about  that in the documentation.

Comment: @Guffa am clueless about method honestly :/

Comment: I am hoping there might be some shortcut in PDF e.g. any ascii code or something I could put in text and PDF will take that as line break

Comment: What made you try HTML code in the text? Do you have any example of HTML code being used with that component?

Comment: @Guffa here is a FAQ but it's for the Form not printing text - https://support.activepdf.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/538/34/webgrabber-2013-headerhtml-and-footerhtml-properties-ignored